# Log In User with Parameters when Changing Password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET App in which want to send an email to a user that presses a Recover Password button that resets the user's password and then sends a link to the user that when followed will log the user in with a new password and bring them to the Change Password page where they must resent their password.

I'm able to reset the password and get the new randomly generated password that I send back to the user in an email.  However, when the user follows the link back with the UserName and pw parameters, the system does not seem to log them in,

Here's the code I am using on the load event that does not seem to work:

```
try
{
    string sUserName = Request.QueryString["UserName"].ToString();
    string sPw = Request.QueryString["pw"].ToString();

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(sUserName, sPw))
    {
        //Log the user in???
        FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(sUserName, sPw);
    }
}

catch (Exception r)
{
    string sMessage = r.Message;
}
```

Any help in logging the user in with username and password parameters would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you shouldn't do that with teh query string.

Comment: Define "does not seem to work."  Is an exception being thrown?  If so, what it is?  What line throws it?  On what line does the logic deviate from what's expected?  What are the states of the objects on that line?  Is there anything to step into with `ValidateUser` and `Authenticate`?  (I suspect not for the latter, but it's certainly possible for the former.)

Comment: I would suggest you don't send a link with a user name and password back through email. Use a one time random string if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) :

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(sUserName, sPw))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sUserName, true);
}
```

In your sample code you are retrieving the user name and password from the query string - this is very bad practice as any observer will see it in plain text. At least use a POST for these values and put them in the body (i.e with a form POST) and always use HTTPS at least for your login page.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(sUserName, sPw))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sUserName, true);
    Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx");
}
```

`FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` is almost same as `FormsAuthentication.ValidateUser`. They just validate user authentication. `SetAuthCookie` creates the authentication ticket(login).

Answer (score 0):

This is how (IMO) reset password functionality should work:

- User clicks button saying "Forgot Password".
- In your code store a random GUID in the DB.
- Send the user an email, with the GUID as a link in the email, as well as their userid, e.g:

> http://yoursite.com/user/reset?guid=a21312738&userid=213123

- On the incoming page, read the userid from the QS, and fetch the user from the DB by this value.
- Compare the stored GUID from the GUID in the QS. If success, render a form that allows the user to change the password via an HTTPS POST.
- In the POST action, change the user's password and sign them in.

You could also go one step further and store an expiration date for the GUID (e.g user must change their password in 24 hours).

Comment: If thats a GUID why is it so short? and also how about sending simply a guid in QS, are you considering someone could guess a whole GUID, so additional userid is needed?

Comment: @Valentin. 1) Of course that's not a *real* guid, it's an example. Do you really think im going to go generate a GUID somewhere for the purposes of an answer? 2) The user id is there so you can fetch the user by id, then compare the guid. If the user id wasnt there, you would need to `FindByGuid` which is a bit silly.

Comment: Ah I see, well one could argue that TryActivate(Guid activateGuid) maybe appropriate method too, but I see your point here.